# Software Updater (update-manager) stuck, but `apt update` and `apt upgrade` work fine. How to fix the update-manager?

Tags: apt, updates, python, software-center

Software Updater (update-manager) stuck, but `apt update` and `apt upgrade` work fine. I have try to use `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.
The error stacktrace is follow:

```bash
update-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 448, in _on_finished
    self._action_done(action,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/__init__.py", line 365, in _action_done
    self.window_main.start_available()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 241, in start_available
    self.refresh_cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 459, in refresh_cache
    self._get_ua_security_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 285, in _get_ua_security_status
    s = json.load(p.stdout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 125, in <module>
    Gtk.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1687, in main
    with register_sigint_fallback(Gtk.main_quit):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 142, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_ossighelper.py", line 237, in register_sigint_fallback
    signal.default_int_handler(signal.SIGINT, None)
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Did you change the system python version?

Comment: The line numbers match 22.04. This is not a Python problem. Line 275 is running `pro security-status --format=json`. What is the output of that command and does it fail?

Comment: Thanks, I found out it. `pro security-status --format=json` and my node environment cause the problem. There is another `pro` which I installed as a global module in my node environment. It overrides the one `/usr/bin/pro`.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not comments

Answer (score 1):

There is a global node module named also `pro` (a Symbolic link) which actually is `@ant-design/pro-cli/cli.js`. It overrides the the correct `pro` in `/usr/bin/pro`. So, when the update-manager run the command `pro security-status --format=json`, it never get the right response.
I just change the `@ant-design/pro-cli/cli.js`'s `pro` to another alias.